# Django static_url when script_name set?

Tags: python, django

So I'm trying to run multiple instances of Django on a server for now, one under `/dev/`, one under `/test/`, etc..

The web server is setting the correct `SCRIPT_NAME` setting and I can serve pages, templates, the whole admin panel fine, except for static assets. Static assets are served by Django using WhiteNoise.

The application is supposed to use the value of `SCRIPT_NAME` as the static URL, ie all static assets are served from the application root.

So far I've tried the following settings against the admin panel:

```
# SCRIPT_NAME = '/dev/' Set in env
# URL for static assets should be `/dev/`
STATIC_URL = '/'  # Browser looks for static assets in `/`, drops script_name
STATIC_URL = None # Browser looks for static assets in `/`, drops script_name
STATIC_URL = `/dev/` # Browser looks for static assets in '/dev/dev/`
```

I'm wondering if I'm missing a setting here or if the problem might be elsewhere. Going by the docs I understand that `STATIC_URL = '/'` should work?

Comment: What WSGI server are you using?

Comment: I had tried gunicorn *and* uwsgi, but I think I've finally found the right combination of settings

Answer (score 8):

Finally got a working config for running my app under `/dev/`:

```
# SCRIPT_NAME = '/dev/' set from uwsgi, or use FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME
STATIC_URL = '/dev/'
WHITENOISE_STATIC_PREFIX = '/'
```

This seems to correctly prepend `/dev/` to all static URLs, and makes whitenoise serve static assets from that directory (no subdir).

Not sure if this is the correct approach though?

Comment: Yes, that's basically the correct approach. The only thing I'd change is to serve static files from a `static/` subdir so:`WHITENOISE_STATIC_PREFIX = '/static/'` and `STATIC_URL = '/dev' + WHITENOISE_STATIC_PREFIX`

Comment: I wanna kiss you, I searched this for 2 hours.
using STATIC_URL = '/my-app/static/'
and WHITENOISE_STATIC_PREFIX = '/static/' works for me

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Geotob. this saved me after so many hours of research. As per docs WhiteNoise 6.2 is supposed to handle this automatically. but some how its not working
http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html?highlight=WHITENOISE_STATIC_PREFIX#WHITENOISE_STATIC_PREFIX

I was hit with this issue when i tried to deploy django with nuxt frontend on Digital Ocean's app platform offering. where my django-drf was running on /api. the admin page wouldn't load with static files on /api/admin/....

finally this setting is working for me. below is my snippet if anyone stumbles upon similar situation.

```
app_route = os.getenv("APP_PLAT_ROUTE", None)

if app_route is not None:
    rel_app_route = os.path.relpath(app_route, '/')
    FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = "/{0}".format(rel_app_route)
    WHITENOISE_STATIC_PREFIX = '/static/'
    STATIC_URL = "/{0}/static/".format(rel_app_route)
```